# How can I configure two different OpenLDAP olcLimits based on user?

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

When runing an `ldapsearch` from the command line using an anonymous bind, I'd like to allow a user/application to have unlimited results returned as long as paging is used.. For the `cn=admin` user, I'd like to allow unlimited results.

I'm using the LDIF file below, but it's not quite right. `cn=admin` is working OK, returning all ~1000 users.

```
# ldapsearch -x -ZZ  -D "cn=admin,dc=my,dc=org" -W
...
# search result
search: 3
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 1082
# numEntries: 1081
```

...but anonymous bind is still limited to 500 results (although paging does work):

```
# ldapsearch -x -ZZ "Objectclass=Person" -E pr=100/prompt
...
# requesting: ALL
# with pagedResults control: size=100
#

# search result
search: 8
result: 4 Size limit exceeded

# numResponses: 506
# numEntries: 500
```

What am I missing? Can't quite seem to get google to return a lot of info about this.

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcLimits
olcLimits: dn.exact="cn=admin,dc=my,dc=org" size=unlimited
  anonymous auth size.pr=500 size.prtotal=unlimited
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem again after upgrading the server and finally figured out how to get it working. Posting it in case anyone else runs across the same problem.

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcLimits
olcLimits: {0}dn.exact="cn=admin,dc=my,dc=org" size=unlimited
-
add: olcLimits
olcLimits: {1}dn.exact="cn=jira_cron,dc=my,dc=org" size=unlimited
-
add: olcLimits
olcLimits: {2}anonymous auth size.pr=500 size.prtotal=unlimited
```